# Compare multiple data from rows

Tags: excel, compare, rows

I'm looking for a way to compare multiple rows with data to each other, trying to find the best possible match. Each number in every column must be an approximately match the other numbers in the same column.

Example:

- Customer #1: **1  5  10  9  7  7  8   2  3**
- Customer #2: 10 5  9   3  5  7  4   3  2
- Customer #3: **1  4  10  9  8  7  6   2  2**
- Customer #4: 9  5  6   7  2  1  10  5  6

In this example customer #1 and #3 is quite similar, and I need to find a way to highlight or sort the rows so I can easily find the best match.

I've tried using conditional formatting to highlight the numbers that are the similar, but that is quite confusing, because the amount of data is quite big.

Any ideas of how I could solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula entered in (say) L1 and pulled down gives the best match with the current row based on the sum of the absolute differences between corresponding cells:-

```
=MIN(IF(ROW($C$1:$K$4)<>ROW(),(MMULT(ABS($C1:$K1-$C$1:$K$4),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$1:$K$4))^0))))
```

It is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can then sort on column L to bring the customers with lowest similarity scores to the top or use conditional formatting to highlight rows with a certain similarity value.

[image]

**EDIT**

If you wanted to penalise large differences in individual columns more heavily than small differences to try and avoid pairs of customers which are fairly similar except for having some columns very different, you could try something like the square of the differences:-

```
=MIN(IF(ROW($C$1:$K$4)<>ROW(),(MMULT(($C1:$K1-$C$1:$K$4)^2,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$1:$K$4))^0))))
```

then the scores for your test data would come out as 7,127,7,127.

Comment: I've tested it out and I works quite well but it's a problem that two rows might have the same score but the score is not necessarily the same in each coloums.
I need to get a good match in each column.

Comment: OK, will give it some thought. Can you tell me if there is a maximum value for the individual score (10?) and also if 7 for customer #1 and in the same column 5 for customer #2 would be regarded as the same as 5 and then 7?

Comment: I think you might need to tell me how much weight to give to the individual differences as opposed to sum of absolute differences.

Comment: The values goes from 1-10. The values is the customers answer on a question where the value 1 is "do not agree" and value 10 is "i do agree". Therefor there is a significant difference in value 5 and 7.
In the end I need to match the answers so I get to find the most similar customers.
Does that make sense? :)

Comment: Therefor if one customer scores 5 and another scores 4 or 6, this would be interesting as well as far as making a good match.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a non-linear weighting system e.g. sum of differences squared so that differences greater than 1 are penalised increasingly heavily. Will add it to my answer.

Comment: Would such a weighting system not look like the one Jonathan sugested below?

Comment: Yes it's similar. Remember that we are just looking at the 4 customers in your question, so we don't have a feel for how it pans out with your real data.

Comment: Ideally if you wanted to take it further you might be looking at some sort of cluster analysis, but that would be way beyond the scope of the original question. However, if you could propose an ad hoc weighting scheme of your own, we could have a look at it.

Comment: BTW the sum of squares is the squared Euclidean distance so there is some theoretical support for it - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_distance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure

Comment: I think it's a bit too advanced for me. For now I think the solution is something simple like Jonathans example.
`=if(B2=$B$1,2,0
+if(B2=$B$1+1,1,0))
+if(B2=$B$1-1,1,0)`
Unless you have a more simple idea? :)

Comment: We could argue all week about this. I have two things against this idea (1) you seem to be throwing away a lot of data (a difference of 2 scores zero, so does a difference of 9) (2) you need 3 if statements just to compare 2 customers on one column so think how many you would need to compare all customers on all columns. Although my formula may look complicated, it does compare the current customer with all other customers on all columns and you can build into it any weighting scheme you choose.

Comment: I know the other solution is very simple and not very comprehensive but the good thing is that it's easier for me to understand.
But I changed your code a bit so it only compares the data to one selected customer (row) and that made it work quite good :)
Thanks for your help, Tom!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Yes just comparing 2 customers at a time would be much easier and then you have the option of making a table out of it - depending how many customers you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to compare customers 2-4 with customer 1 and that you are comparing only within each column. In this case, you could implement a 'scoring system' using multiple IFs. For example,:

```
    A              B     C    D    E
1   Customer 1     1     1    2
2   Customer 2     1     2    2
3   Customer 3     0     1    0
```

you could use in E2

```
=if(B2=$B$1,1,0)+if(C2=$C$1,1,0)+if(D2=$D$1,1,0)
```

This will return a 'score' of 1 when you have a match and a 'score' of 0 when you don't. It then adds up the scores and your highest value will be your best match. Copying down would then give

```
    A              B     C    D    E
1   Customer 1     1     1    2
2   Customer 2     1     2    2    2
3   Customer 3     0     1    0    1
```

so customer 2 is the best match.

Comment: Not a bad idea - it could work quite well.
What would you advice if I needed to make a "buffer" as well so it also scores those numbers that are closer than 2 points?

Comment: Ofcause more IF's would do:
=if(B2=$B$1,2,0)+if(B2+1=$B$1,1,0)+if(B2-1=$B$1,1,0)

Just a bit of a mess and many IF's :)

Comment: If you wanted to reward close matches, you could take them away from each other and reward the lowest score. So, if customer 1 had 1,2,3 and customer 2 had 2,2,4, you could do =abs(1-2)+abs(2-2)+abs(3-4)=2. The customer with the lowest score is the best match. (Abs gives the absolute value i.e. the number without the sign)

Comment: Or, to only reward matches less than two, use =if(abs(b1-b2)<=2,1,0.